# Getting context from getContext() or from constructor as a field

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-context

Let's use custom or extending View as an example.

Is it more effective to save `Context` parameter from constructor as a field, than calling `getContext()` everywhere (supposing there are, let's say, 10 or more places where it is needed)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`View#getContext()` is

```
class View {
    protected Context mContext;
    public final Context getContext() {
        return mContext;
    }
}
```

and a locally cached implementation:

```
class X {
    private final Context mLocalContext;
    public X(Context ctx) {
        mLocalContext = ctx;
    }
}
```

Now there is a very small difference when you use `mLocalContext` instead of `getContext()`. The JVM can get to the required reference of the context object without having to execute the method (which takes a tiny bit of extra time). That call can't be optimized away since `View#mContext` is mutable (can change). In the local example it can assume that `mLocalContext` can't change and optimize the code a little better. [Note: I am not 100% sure about what optimizations are / can be done]

The difference might be measurable if you use the context a lot but in this case it does not matter much. It's still a good idea to cache Objects locally if you need them often. Especially when their (re)construction takes time (e.g. when `getContext()` would create a `new Context()` or so).

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using getContext() every where, it is better to  pass current context as argument in constructor where you wanna to use.

Comment: I agree with Agarwal. Storing a value locally is the fastest approach; even for fast, light weight functions like `getContext()`.  Here's the Dev Guide on [Designing for Performance](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/performance.html), check out the section "Avoid Internal Getters/Setters".

Answer (score 1):

It looks like, from the source code, the View's constructor stores the context parameter and that's what getContext() returns:

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/view/View.java#View.getContext%28%29

So, my instinct would be that storing the parameter yourself would be redundant, since the super class is already doing it for you.